# Setting stack size for vivado hls in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: stack, ubuntu-16.04, vivado-hls

How can I increase the stack size in vivado hls in ubuntu 16.04?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a large stack size? Perhaps you can replace local variables with static variables or globals?

Comment: Because Its simple